# Why I can only connect with UseDefaultCredentials option

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a web service ( old .NET 2.0 way) running on a VM machine and from my Dev machine that is a Win 7 I want to test it. If I set domain, user name, password wit something like this for testing:

```
NetworkCredential userPass = new NetworkCredential();
Cytowebservice.TransferService m_servie = new Cytowebservice.TransferService();

userPass.Domain = domain;
userPass.UserName = username;
userPass.Password = passwordTextBox.Text;
m_servie.Credentials = userPass;
```

then when I want to call one of its webmethods I get a 401.1 Authorization error. But I am NOT typing my user/pass wrong. BUT if I do not use them and just say

```
m_servie.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

then it connects without error. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are not showing any useful code so that we can help you.

Comment: like what? I have pasted the code and the error. What else do you think is needed? so I can provide it.

Comment: what are `userPass` and `m_servie`?, How do you create them? Do you use `CookieContainer`? etc.

Comment: @BDotA - Have you tried assigning `m_servie.Credentials` to `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` to see if it still works?

Comment: @L.B: userpass is NetworkCredential userPass = new NetworkCredential();   and m_service is Cytowebservice.TransferService m_servie = new Cytowebservice.TransferService(); where CytoWebService is the name I have used for my WebRefrence to that webservice.

Comment: @M.Babcock: Ok I tried it. CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; worked too, same as UseDefaultCredentials that had worked before. But I need that user/pass to get it to work and know why that one fails. Thanks

Comment: @BDotA - Great so now you know that you can connect when explicitly passing valid credentials. So what's wrong with the ones you're passing?

Comment: @M.Babcock: I don't know man! when I call one of the webmethods of that service, it crashes and gives a 401.1 Authorization Access error. But I know I am not typing my user/pass wrong.

Comment: OK, That info is enough for a -1. Think how you could help me If I had asked that question

Comment: @BDotA - Are you in a domain?

Comment: Yes, I am. I put a break point and made sure the domain/user/pass I am passing to is is correct, my domain and user is something like XYZ_NT_DOMAIN\MyUserName  and then I also have my password. so I pass XYZ_NT_DOMAIN as domain name and MyUserName section as username and then also password of course.

Comment: @BDotA - Are you passing the domain with the username? (DOMAIN\UserName)

Comment: @M.Babcock no I pass them separately,  DOMAIN for its domain, UserName for its username, etc

Comment: @BDotA - Try leaving the domain blank and passing the domain qualified username in the username field. If that doesn't work then pass the domain in the domain field and the domain qualified username in the username field. It may be a stretch but I've seen this act inconsistently in different environments.

Comment: @M.Babcock: please use your last comment as "Answer" and I will mark it as correct. Thank you so much for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try leaving the domain blank and passing the domain qualified username in the username field. If that doesn't work then pass the domain in the domain field and the domain qualified username in the username field. It may be a stretch but I've seen this act inconsistently in different environments.